# Medical X-Ray Tube Energy

Tags: x-rays

Is there any way to calculate the mean energy of emitted x-rays in kev if the source have voltage of 140 kV and current is 1.25 mA?

Comment: It depends on the voltage and anode material. It doesn't depend on the current. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_tube